# Select option isn't working

Tags: jquery, xml, select, mobile

I'm really new to jquery and I am not a "tumbleweed" )-; so please keep that in mind.

I have a jquery mobile app that current posts data to an api.

I have three xml documents based on daily, weekly, and monthly activities generated by an api. I need to take the value a user selects from three options (Previous Day Summary, Previous Week Summary, and Previous Month Summary) to call the correct XML document already provided for that time period, parse the XML document to locate three nodes, and then write the text from those nodes to a div for a different page of the jquery mobile application.

Right now the app isn't calling the select change function. I'd appreciate any insight into what I'm doing wrong on that issue as well as any other suggestions for improving on my overall work here.

**The XML document structure follows:**

```
<StatusModel>

<Uid>
 xxxxxxx
 </Uid>

<Created>
2011-08-02T08:57:39.377
</Created>

<User>
xxxxxx
</User>

<Level>
x
</Level>

<Doing>
xxxxx
</Doing>

<Thinking>
xxxxx
</Thinking>

</StatusModel>
```

**The html for the select is as follows:**

```
 <div data-role="fieldcontain">
 <label for="summaries" class="select">Review a summary of your scores and notes:</label>
   <select name="summaries" id="summaries" data-native-menu="false">
      <option value="time_period" selected>Choose a time period</option>
      <option value="Previous_Day_Summary">Previous Day Summary</option>
      <option value="Last_Week_Summary">Last Week Summary</option>
      <option value="Last_Month_Summary">Last Month Summary</option>
     </select>  
 </div>
```

**The script is as follows:**

```
$(function() {

$('[name = "summaries"]').change(function() {

alert("selection called");

$(this).children(":selected").text();

//getting the text from the summaryreviews form selection

var newVal = $("#summaries").val();

//newurl builds the url based on the timeframe chosen in the summaryreviews select box

var newurl = $("http://somedomainname/api/list" + "newVal");


$.ajax( {
type: "GET",
url: (newurl),
cache: false,
dataType: "xml",
success: summaryxml

});

function summaryxml(xml) {

    //parse the xml document including children using the *;

$(xml).find(*).each(function() {

    var level = $(this).find("level").text();
    var doing = $(this).find("doing").text();
    var thinking = $(this).find("thinking").text();


$('<li>' + 'level' + '<br />' + 'doing' + '<br />' + 'thinking' +  '</p></li>').appendTo("#summarylist");

//refresh the summarylist

$("#summarylist").listview('refresh');

    });
}

});

 });
```

**The div I want to populate is on another jquery mobile page**

```
<div data-role="page" id="summarynotes" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed" data-transition="slide">
<div data-role="header">

</div>


<div data-role="content" id="summarize" data-theme="d">


<ul id="summarylist" data-role="listview">

// Display Day, Week, or Month summary notes here


</ul>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that the change event handler isn't being called? I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/8eEGQ/2/) based on your code and don't see a problem with the change event.

Comment: @Spycho, yes I do mean that the change event handler isn't being called. The alert is not shown. I'm running FF 5.0

Comment: I too am running FF5. Do you get the same problem in the fiddle I posted?

Comment: Yes @Spycho, I see a dropdown but it doesn't display options. I've fixed that part of the code by changing the event handler. I've changed that part of the example. There are other issues with the example that I'm trying to work through now.

Comment: Perhaps our versions of Firefox are marginally different. I'm on Ubuntu. I guess my browser copes better with slightly malformed JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts that hopefully help:

- did you mean to call document.ready on Line 1 of your JS? i.e. `$(function() {`
- Line 3 - why not just use address your `select` by its ID? `$('#summaries').change()`
- `var newurl = $("http://somedomainname/api/list" + "newVal");` -- this will evaluate to `http://somedomainname/api/listnewVal`. Is that what you intended?

Comment: on point one regarding the $(function(){ code it was a mistake. On point number two, I changed it using your suggestion and that worked. On point number three, what I'm trying to do is append the text of one of the selections from #summaries to "http://somedomainname/api/list". I'll fiddle with the code and see what needs changing. The change event handler is called in FF, Opera, and Safari so your answer works

Answer (score 1):

To begin with change

```
$(xml).find(*).each(function() {
```

into

```
$(xml).find('*').each(function() {
```

If you use a good IDE with syntax highlighting you may easier find this kind of mistakes.

Good luck.

@Spycho's comment: it works in Firefox, but doesn't in IE/Opera...

Comment: @Spycho, yes I do mean that the change event handler isn't being called. The alert is not shown.

Comment: yep I see your point, thanks. Which IDE do you recommend? Sorry about putting the answer here but I missed the time limit on the Edit box for your comment.

Comment: Easy to use, no-hassle IDE: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/
IDE for bigger projects, lots of great options, slightly more difficult: http://netbeans.org/